# JSP is not parsing page directive

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp

JSP is not getting parsed on browser. Instead show the directive directly.
Can anyone help me out

```html
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
                Sample
            </title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <button id="generateTicket">Generate Ticket</button>
            <div id='ticket'></div>
            <script>
                $("#generateTicket").click(
                        function(){
                            console.log("Generate ticket");
                            $("#ticket").load("generateTicket");
                        });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

below is the image of pom.xm

[image]

Comment: What servlet rev in `web.xml`? Anything turning off JSP anywhere?

Comment: i am not using web.xml, i am using spring boot. configured the pom.xml as updated below
Below is the updated pom.xml
POM.xml:

     ...
     <dependencies>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependencies>

Comment: Yes well I can't read that; put code in the question please.